# Magento 2.3.0 - Add custom block after product description tabs

Tags: magento2, php, static-block, magento2.3, product-page

I've created a CMS block called

> km_product_page_short_description

I want to call this CMS block in a custom block below the product description tabs (where the blue line is) as shown in the screenshot below

[image]

How can I do this?

I tried the following but it shows under add to cart instead of under product description tabs.

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="myPromo" after="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">km_product_page_short_description</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
```

---

UPDATE:

I have used this code block to get the custom CMS Block, however it shows above the product details tabs, instead of below the tabs.

[image]

```
 <referenceContainer name="content"> 
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="km_product_page_short_description" after="-"> 
        <arguments> 
        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">km_product_page_short_description</argument> 
        </arguments> 
        </block> 
        </referenceContainer>
```

Below is the entire code catalog_product_view.xml with the

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="product.info.wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="row">
                <container name="product.info.col.media" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-md-12 col-lg-6" />
                <container name="product.info.col.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                    <container name="product.info.col.main.wrap" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="tt-product-single-info" />
                </container>
            </container>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.details.bot" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/details.bottom.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes.bot" as="additional.bot" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info_bot">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Product Details</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description.bot" as="description.bot" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info_bot">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
                        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Description</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>


        <referenceContainer name="content.aside">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Additional" name="product.info.additional.bot" as="product_additional_data_bot"/>
        </referenceContainer>


        <referenceContainer name="content"> 
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="km_product_page_short_description" after="-"> 
        <arguments> 
        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">km_product_page_short_description</argument> 
        </arguments> 
        </block> 
        </referenceContainer>


        <block class="Ecomwares\Wokiee\Block\Template" name="product_socials" template="html/product_socials.phtml"/>
        <block class="Ecomwares\Wokiee\Block\Template" name="product_labels" template="html/product_labels.phtml"/>
        <block class="Ecomwares\Wokiee\Block\Template" name="product_countdown" template="html/product_countdown.phtml"/>

        <move element="product.info.wrapper" destination="content" before="-" />
        <move element="product.info.media" destination="product.info.col.media"/>
        <move element="product.info.main" destination="product.info.col.main.wrap"/>
        <move element="product.info.details.bot" destination="main.content" after="main.content.indent"/>
        <move element="product_socials" destination="main.content" after="product.info.details.bot"/>
        <move element="catalog.product.related" destination="main.content" after="product_socials"/>
        <move element="product.info.upsell" destination="main.content" after="catalog.product.related"/>

        <move element="page.main.title" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>
        <move element="product_labels" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>
        <move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.price"/>

        <move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" after="product-add-form"/>
        <move element="product.info.review" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.overview"/>
        <move element="product_countdown" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.overview"/>
        <move element="product.info.type" destination="product.info.stock.sku" after="product.info.sku"/>
        <move element="product.info.details" destination="product.info.main" after="-"/>

        <move element="product.attributes.bot" destination="product.info.details.bot"/>
        <move element="product.info.description.bot" destination="product.info.details.bot" after="product.attributes.bot"/>


    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the  after tab value to

`after="product.info.detail"` from  `after="-"`

**Change the line**

```
block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="myPromo" after="-"
```

**to**

```
block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="myPromo" after="product.info.detail"
```

Comment: For what and where?

Comment: I want to show new phtml or cms block after product.info.detail is there anyway?

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to add the block after product description tab then use below code.**

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="km_product_page_short_description" after="product.info.details">
<arguments>
    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">km_product_page_short_description</argument>
</arguments>
</block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: This displays the block above the tabs (product details) block.

Comment: Try this code:                                                                       
<referenceContainer name="content">
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="km_product_page_short_description" after="-">
<arguments>
    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">km_product_page_short_description</argument>
</arguments>
</block>
</referenceContainer>

Comment: Thanks, but that still doesnt work, show above the tabs block.

Comment: <move element="product.info.details" destination="product.info.main" after="-"/>

you have moved "product.info.details" in "product.info.main".
you just need to pass the name of section where you want to place the "product.info.details" in after element instead of putting "-" in after.

Comment: I tried everything, <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="km_product_page_short_description" after="product.info.details"> | <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="km_product_page_short_description" after="product.info.details.bot"> | <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="km_product_page_short_description" after="product.info.main"> nothing moves the block after the tabs block